# Check if polygon has been clicked

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-store-apps, polygon

Hi I have added a polygon to a map using:

```
//Creating a Polygon
Polygon MyPolygon = new Polygon(); 
MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(95, 0));
MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(95, 35));
MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(10, 35));
MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 75)); // 

MyPolygon.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
MyPolygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

//Creating a MapOverlay and adding the Grid to it.
MapOverlay MyOverlay = new MapOverlay();
MyOverlay.Content = MyPolygon;
MyOverlay.GeoCoordinate = 
new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude,     coordinate.Longitude);
MyOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0, 1.0);

//Creating a MapLayer and adding the MapOverlay to it            
mapLayer.Add(MyOverlay);

MyPolygon.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MyPolygon_Click);
```

...

```
private void MyPolygon_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock nametext;
    nametext = new TextBlock { Text = "1234" };          
}
```

I need to check if the user clicks on this polygon. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Have you tried adding a MouseUp Eventhandler to your Polygon?

Comment: Yes.I have edited my question to show this but nothing happens when the polygon is clicked.

Comment: What framework is are you using ? WPF, Windows Store or ?

Comment: Your click event only creates a text block, it does not show it. So maybe the even is triggered but nothing to be shown.

Comment: How do I show the textblock on the screen?

Comment: If this is a Windows Store app, I do not believe you have MouseLeftButtonUp events, the store apps have Pointer events like PointerPressed, PointerReleased, PointerMoved etc. Is this maybe a desktop WPF app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a store app, the following code below is a quick and dirty sample that will react and add a TextBlock at the location you click on or touch the screen.

XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="StoreApp_PolyTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:StoreApp_PolyTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Canvas 
        Name="canvas"
        Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        Loaded="Canvas_Loaded">

    </Canvas>
</Page>
```

Code behind

```
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace StoreApp_PolyTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Canvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Polygon MyPolygon = new Polygon();
            MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
            MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(95, 0));
            MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(95, 35));
            MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(10, 35));
            MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 75)); // 

            MyPolygon.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            MyPolygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

            canvas.Children.Add(MyPolygon);

            MyPolygon.PointerPressed += MyPolygon_PointerPressed;
        }

        void MyPolygon_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock nameText = new TextBlock() {Text="1234"};
            var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
            Canvas.SetLeft(nameText, point.Position.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(nameText, point.Position.Y);
            canvas.Children.Add(nameText);
        }
    }
}
```